# Identifying distinct sets of rows in SQL

Tags: sql, t-sql, azure-sql-database, azure-sql

I'd like to uniquely identify groups of rows that use the same grouping.

For example, if we imagine some epos data, I'd like to identify the customers that bought the exact same combination of items, relating them all to a definition of the set (see example below).

This feels like a window function problem, but I'm still trying to figure out how to use them to identify a unique combination of rows, rather than partitioning by a customer or item.

In the below example, I would like to identify all occurrences of only red and blue as set 1, green and yellow as set 2 etc. the number of rows/values in the mapping is unbounded so pivoting and then grouping/joining would not be suitable.

[image]

What would be the easiest way to go about this?

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The simplest method is actually string aggregation.  In Standard SQL, this looks like:

```
select items,
       listagg(customerid, ',') within group (order by customerid) as customerids,
       row_number() over (order by items) as group_id
from (select customerid, 
             listagg(item, ',') within group (order by item) as items
      from t
     ) c
group by items;
```

The result set is not exactly what you specify, because the ids are combined together in a single row.

EDIT:

In SQL Server, the syntax would use `string_agg()`:

```
select items,
       string_agg(customerid, ',') within group (order by customerid) as customerids,
       row_number() over (order by items) as group_id
from (select customerid, 
             string_agg(item, ',') within group (order by item) as items
      from t
     ) c
group by items;
```

Comment: That would do it exactly, from this it's easy to generate an ID if I'd like to or identify matching items